# Java fileOutputStream

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I have been looking around but could not find what I need.
I am writing a simple code to save some strings into a .txt file.

I am using:

```
File archivo = new File(FileName);
fileOutputStream.write(toString().getBytes());
fileOutputStream.flush();
```

When I do this the .txt is succesfully created and save the info I need to save, BUT it save all in 1 single huge line.
How I can save it in diffent lines?

example when I open the txt:

```
This is line 1This is line 2This is line 3This is line 4
```

I have add '\n' at the end of each string but it doesn't work.

toString() return a String: "This is line 1";
OS: Windows 7

Comment: What is the result of the method `toString()`? Can you show us the code of this method?

Comment: Are you running on a Windows OS?

Comment: Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try doing something like this:

```
public void write(final File file, final List<String> lines) throws IOException{
    final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); //new FileWriter(file, true) if you want to append the file (default is false)
    for(final String line : lines){
        writer.write(line);
        writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

If you are using Java 8, feel free to try using lambdas:

```
public void write(final File file, final List<String> lines) throws IOException{
    final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); //new FileWriter(file, true) if you want to append the file (default is false)
    lines.forEach(
            l -> {
                try{
                    writer.write(l);
                    writer.newLine();
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    );
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

For usage, you could try this:

`write(new File(fileName), Arrays.asList("This is line 1", "This is line 2", "This is line 3", "This is line 4"));`

Answer (score 0):

Use **System.getProperty("line.separator")**, which will return sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files.

Try like this.

```
File archivo = new File(FileName);
fileOutputStream.write(toString().getBytes());
fileOutputStream.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
fileOutputStream.flush();
```

Ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add '\n' to a StringBuilder before write.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("line 1" + "\n");
sb.append("line 2" + "\n");
sb.append("line 3" + "\n");
```

`fileOutputStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes());`